# pg_restore fails with materialized view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I’m trying to pg_restore a db dump that contain a materialized views.

If it is relevant, the materialized view is of a foreign data wrapper.

It fails with the following errors:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 354; 1259 266280 MATERIALIZED VIEW x_daily_stats_mv u5cuus46hhtdfs
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  user mapping not found for "erik"
    Command was: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW x_daily_stats_mv AS
 SELECT x_daily_stats_v.campaign_id,
    x_daily_stats_v.t...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "x_daily_stats_mv" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE x_daily_stats_mv OWNER TO u5cuus46hhtdfs;



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4056; 1259 433791 INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_campaign_id u5cuus46hhtdfs
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "x_daily_stats_mv" does not exist
    Command was: CREATE INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_campaign_id ON x_daily_stats_mv USING btree (campaign_id);



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4057; 1259 433793 INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_creative_id u5cuus46hhtdfs
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "x_daily_stats_mv" does not exist
    Command was: CREATE INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_creative_id ON x_daily_stats_mv USING btree (creative_id);



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4058; 1259 433790 INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_date u5cuus46hhtdfs
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "x_daily_stats_mv" does not exist
    Command was: CREATE INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_date ON x_daily_stats_mv USING btree (date);



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4059; 1259 433792 INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_targeting_group_id u5cuus46hhtdfs
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "x_daily_stats_mv" does not exist
    Command was: CREATE INDEX x_daily_stats_mv_targeting_group_id ON x_daily_stats_mv USING btree (targeting_group_id);



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4484; 0 266280 MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA x_daily_stats_mv u5cuus46hhtdfs
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "x_daily_stats_mv" does not exist
    Command was: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW x_daily_stats_mv;



WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 7
```

Looks like errors 2-7 are because the materialized view doesn't exist -- but why did it fail in the first place?  User `erik` is my local superuser.

Comment: It is absolutely related to the FDW - there you need a user mapping, which is missing at the time of MV creation.  Check your dump if it is included at all.

Comment: @dezso When I grep through the dump file, the user mapping and other FDW stuff appears to be there...

Comment: And the fdw and related stuff doesn't throw an error, too?

Comment: The errors I posted are the only ones in the output.